# JqueryUI appears to be very old version, how to update?

Tags: ee2, jquery, javascript

Been building a new form with Expression Engine 2.9.2, however when trying to use the datepicker, it seems to be using a very old version of JQuery UI, so old that it only actually functions at all in Chrome.

Both Firefox and IE (latest and older versions I've tested) don't actually get a working date-picker at all, they literally get no field. I've tried using it as a date field, a text field and several classes the datepicker is mean to pick up (datepicker, hasDatepicker).

Looking at it, this seems be a very old version of JQuery UI from several years ago which explains why it doesn't function, however when I download the latest version, the file layout and names are all completely different so its not just a simple matter of replacing the files with the more up to date versions.

So, is there a relatively simple way to update the version of JQuery UI that EE use or is it easier to just disable the EE built-in datepicker and use an external one to do the same job?

I'm also curious as to why EE would be using such an old version of JQuery UI?

Comment: I've always found it easier to add include_assets="no" and include the external files that you need manually. That way you have a lot more control and can pick and choose the files/scripts you need.

Comment: Thats what I'm going at the moment, was hoping there was an easier way ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way, but I've just answered a similar question here : [EE 2.10.1 jQuery & jQuery UI update](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/31443/ee-2-10-1-jquery-jquery-ui-update/31455#31455)

Of course Brandon's answer seems alot more succinct!!!